# How to get search results where the search keyword is equal to column X?

Tags: 2013, search

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have edited the search content webpart on the search page. I have configured this webpart to show only items from contenttype "Customers". It works. When I search now on for example "Microsoft", I get all the items where the search key word "Microsoft" is available in the columns "Title" and "Description". But I have a custom column "CompanyName". I would like to check this column for the search result. How can I implement this?

Comment: I haven't tried it though but I believe in 'Change query builder' you can specify the required managed property for limiting the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the column needs to be Indexable
2. Under administration console of SP > Service Application > Search Service Application
3. Search Schema > New Managed Property
4. Create your property
5. Run a full crawl
6. Go to your centre search site (usually: `http://mymachinename/search`) and try do to a search on that column to understand if it comes up
7. Add the value on your JSLink, WebPart or wherever you need it
8. Then you can search using the Keyword Query Language like this:

   CompanyName:"Microsoft"

Comment: And how can I exclude the Title and description columns from the search? I dont want that SharePoint search on the search keyword in the "Title" and "Description" columns. Only in my custom column "CompanyName"

Comment: @KHA I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the Query in the Search Results Web part to read: `CompanyName:{searchTerms}`